# VS Code re-installation: Pylance now complains about arcpy, but intellisense, code completion, and script execution works ok

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro, visual-studio-code

I was recently victim to [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/52855) where VS Code (Insiders) seems to uninstall itself. After a reinstallation, most of my settings and preferences were retained, but Pylance is now complaining about arcpy:

[image: VS Code screenshot]

Everything else seems to work ok; intellisense, code completion, typings, definition inspection, etc. I can debug, step thru the code, inspect everything inside the arcpy package so it appears to work normally; this is more of an annoyance than anythign I guess.. Has anyone encountered this with VS Code and the Python/Pylance extensions and been able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing a full nuke & pave reinstallation:

- Uninstall VS Code Insiders
- Sign out of all other synced VS Code Insiders installations and delete all synced data from cloud
- Remove folder `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode-insiders\`
- Remove folder `%APPDATA%\Code - Insiders\`
- Run VS Code Insiders [installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)
- Re-configure as had been previously; issues are no longer detected by VS Code with the arcpy package